# laravel-er-diagram-generator - Graphviz

Tags: php, laravel, package, erd

I just installed via composer `beyondcode/laravel-er-diagram-generator`. I did all the required steps from

> https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-er-diagram-generator/tree/f4a0f01a4f141e508766521158839a419566ff07

but when I try to actually generate a diagram that is: `php artisan generate:erd output.png`

I get the following **error**:

> An error occurred while creating the graph;
>   GraphViz returned: Error:
>   : syntax error in line 1642 near '-'

I have no idea what it means? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:
run this instead of `php artisan generate:erd output.png`

```
php artisan generate:erd --format=text
```

This will give you a textual representation of the graph from your models `app/Models`.

`Terminal shot`
[terminal shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TffNd.png)

Copy the text from your terminal and paste it in the url below
Then you can try and paste this into a tool like: https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/

Image generated from for erd:  [Erd genrated from models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulIkQ.png)